# maybe vs. may be

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation

> maybe vs. may be

I wonder, if spoken fast, how do native speakers differentiate the two?

Would there be any advice?

Comment: There is sometimes an audible difference which can give away the intended word(s), but it is not 100% reliable and is difficult to explain without actual audio examples.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to differentiate these two, if spoken fast, is to check the grammar of the sentence.

E.g.

> Are you going somewhere? Maybe.

> I may be going somewhere.

Here "I maybe going somewhere" is wrong, but using "may be" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

A native English speaker would often know the difference between "may be" and "maybe" based on the context.  However it would hardly be something they consider in everyday conversation, as the practical usage and meaning of both "may be" and "maybe" are almost the same.

Try switching the instance of *may be/maybe* with *possibly* or *perhaps*; is the response still valid?  *Possibly* and *perhaps* are adverbs like *maybe*, so if the sentence is still valid then the intended word was probably *maybe*.

**Example 1:** Imagine these two responses to the question "Are you going to the dance tonight?"

> I may be.

Replace *may be* with *possibly* and the response is no longer valid: "I *possibly*."

> Maybe.

Replace with *possibly* and the response is still valid: "*Possibly*."

**Example 2:** "Maybe we should head back, I may be in trouble if we don't."

We can try our replacements and see what makes sense.

> *Possibly/perhaps* we should head back,

Both technically work, though *perhaps* sounds better in this case.  Either way, we know we have a *maybe*.

> I *possibly/perhaps* in trouble if we don't.

This doesn't sound right with either word, and so we know it must be *may be*.